# Only show if exists in other table

Tags: php, mysql, match, categories

I'm new to PHP and MySQL and right now I'm showing a table with categories from products. But I'm trying to only show them if they exist in another table. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to get there.

Currently, I'm showing ALL categories like this:

```php
<?php include '/../connect.php'; ?>

<?php

$results=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM groepen");
while($rows=$results->fetch_array())
{ 
    ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo 'groep?id='.$rows['GroepID']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['GroepOmschrijving']; ?></a>

    <?php
    $result=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM subgroepen WHERE GroepID=".$rows['GroepID']);
    ?>
    <ul>                
        <?php  
        while($row=$result->fetch_array())
        {
            ?><li><a href="<?php echo 'subgroep?id=' . $row['SubGroepID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['SubGroepOmschrijving']; ?></a></li><?php
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
    </li>   

    <?php
}
?>
```

So, I'm trying to only show the categories if the value of table `groepen.GroepID` matches the value of `occasions.Groepnummer`.

Comment: Look for MYSQL JOIN. With an join you can connect two databases based on a statement or condition in your case the groupid

Comment: @Ann-SophieAngermüller just to be precise with join you connect two or more tables not databases :)

Comment: Yeah you are totally correct @LelioFaieta I don't even know why i wrote this sh"t

Comment: Thanks a lot! INNER JOIN did the trick!